# SERIALITY() plugin installation on firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Please help me to understand how to install the Seriality Plugin (www.zambetti.com/projects/seriality/‎) in Chrome or Firefox.

I want to read from a COM Port on the client side of a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Google code site, this site contains the DMG file you can use to install the Seriality.plugin file.

https://code.google.com/p/seriality/

You can also see the sample source on the site that shows the javascript to use the plugin, below is a snippet shown on the site that prints "Hello World" to the first port seen on the system at a baudrate of 9600 when this HTML file is loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    function setup()
    {
      var serial = (document.getElementById("seriality")).Seriality();
      serial.begin(serial.ports[0], 9600);
      serial.write("Hello World");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="setup();">
  <object type="application/Seriality" id="seriality" width="0" height="0"></object>
</body>
</html>
```